# How to define instance methods from wrap

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django site and want to define some instance methods like below.

```
Class Auth(models.Model):
    def wrap_has_perm(self, perm):
        def wrap():
            if self.is_staff and self.has_perm(perm):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    can_add_order = wrap_has_perm('finance.normal')

    can_review_order = wrap_has_perm('finance.review')

    is_leader = wrap_has_perm('finance.leader')

    is_finance = wrap_has_perm('finance.finance')
```

I want to use `can_add_order`, `can_review_order`, `is_leader`, `is_finance` as django admin site's list_display element. But now these instance methods is illegal.(TypeError: wrap_has_perm() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given))

How can I achieve these methods?

If I use partial:

```
def staff_has_perm(self, perm):
        return self.is_staff and self.has_perm(perm)

    can_add_order = partial(staff_has_perm, perm='finance.normal')
    can_review_order = partial(staff_has_perm, perm='finance.review')
    is_leader = partial(staff_has_perm, perm='finance.leader')
    is_finance = partial(staff_has_perm, perm='finance.finance')
```

It raises (*** TypeError: staff_has_perm() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given));
Should I pass `self` to and how to ?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `self` to `wrap()`'s definition:

```
def wrap_has_perm(perm):
    def wrap(self):
```

However, a more Pythonic way to do this might be to use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

class Auth(models.Model):
    def has_perm(self, perm):
        # ...

    can_add_order = partial(has_perm, perm='finance.normal')

    can_review_order = partial(has_perm, perm='finance.review')

    is_leader = partial(has_perm, perm='finance.leader')

    is_finance = partial(has_perm, perm='finance.finance')
```

Comment: The more Pythonic way is incorrect. It may cause (TypeError at /admin/auth/user/ staff_has_perm() takes exactly 2 arguments). Because of list_disply demands only one arg.